# What does "not to seem uninformed" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Professor: Well, she's really versatile. She just spent several months studying social interactions in Indonesia, and she's been influential in ethnology. Oh, and she's also done work in South America. That's closer to biology—especially with speciation.
Student: **Uh, not to seem uninformed...**
Professor: Well, how species form… you know, how two distinct species form from one...

Comment: Student: I don't want you to think I am ignorant ... [but what is speciation?]

Answer (score 2):

This is a conversational strategy (that is probably common across languages) of starting a sentence, but not finishing it, because it can be assumed that the listener will understand the implication.  It can be an example of *tact* or polite *tentativeness*, or to avoid embarrassment.

Here there is an infinitive phrase that could function as an introductory phrase in a sentence.  "To appear uninformed" is to seem as if one hasn't been educated. And I would understand "Not to appear uninformed" to mean something like "I don't want to seem to be uneducated but ..."

The "but ..." is "but I don't understand the meaning of 'speciation'." It may be embarrassing to admit to a professor that you don't know the meaning of a word, so the speaker omits this part.  However, the professor understands and tactfully explains.

Comment: Not wishing to seem inquisitive, but does your mother have a drink problem?